# Squid LAN network Per user Bandwidth monitoring

Tags: lan, monitoring, squid, bandwidth

I have made a small LAN network with a ubuntu squid proxy server. The proxy server runs in my laptop with VMware where it is placed in between the ADSL router and 4 port switch. I have added 3 user pcs to the switch as in the below LAN diagram. The connection for the switch goes through my server laptops ethernet port while setting up in this way the connection of the LAN works successfully, also the LAN users are able to access the internet through squid proxy server all the ACL restrictions too work fine. I wanted to know is there any possibility of monitoring the users Internet bandwidth in this network?

I used iftop and nethogs but it only monitors the eth0 bandwidth. I want to monitor per user as in the network , please help me out if there's a way

Connection details

- Internet Connection to the server laptop is through wifi
- Ubuntu server uses DHCP
- LAN users gets their ip by DHCP
- LAN user can ping to my server IP address
- Internet Connection for the LAN users works

This is the LAN network design

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](http://superuser.com/questions/1069924/monitor-internet-bandwidth-of-lan-users). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 0):

The most effective solution for this is to use the Wireshark packet sniffer. This allows you to sort packets on port, protocol, IP, and view streams of packet / packet info. Unfortunately this does not give you an instant overview of web pages for example, but there are a lot of tutorials available to help you get started with Wireshark.

There is a guide on how to install Wireshark in Ubuntu [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DBZiKpbHO0).

[Download Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/#download)

[Wireshark Beginner's Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0l_54thSYU)

Comment: Thanks for the reply budy , well thing is i need to monitor the bandwidth of the users from the server lap itself. Like monitoring them from the ubuntu server , im using the squid proxy server for these LAN users so if theres away to monitor them from the squid prxy would be great as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would give [Pandora FMS](http://pandorafms.com) a try, specially since they've reinforced their network monitoring capabilities by incorporating [Netflow monitoring](http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Netflow).

Comment: If your devices are not compatible with Netflow, I suggest trying the IPTraf plugin they have on the [Pandora FMS library](http://library.pandorafms.com/?sec=Library&sec2=repository&lng=en&tag=276).